# Why do Bioware think I'm Canadian?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Not that I have anything against Canadians or Canada, never been there I'm sure it's a lovely place full of quite wonderful people.

So if you log onto the BioWare Social Network and go to **My Games** -> **Mass Effect 3** -> **Leaderboards** then you can see your rankings in three categories: Global, Country and Friends

Mine currently looks like this (names and scores obscured to protect the pathetic): 
[image]

I'd much prefer to know how I rank in England/UK/Britain/Europe than knowing what Canadians are up to!

The Edit Profile on BSN has a "Location" text box, which I've typed "UK" into. The Account Settings has my timezone as GMT. My Xbox and Live account are UK accounts. Following the Add Bioware Points link offers me prices in Pound Sterling, so that's picking up my location ok.

What have I missed, why have I become an honorary Canadian?

EDIT: The plot thickens, [Gh0sT's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/57227/263) sent me off to my [EA profile settings](https://profile.ea.com/) where I see this, showing that I've already set my account to UK (which makes sense as I do have an active SWTOR sub and have, reluctantly, bought from Origin in the past, and credit cards do insist on checking your address as they're validated.

[image]

BSN still thinks I'm Canadian :(

Comment: Too much maple syrup of course

Comment: I hope the answer comes soon i dont want this to happen to me

Comment: Huh.  Even geolocation shouldn't peg you that far out of your area.  You sure you didn't put 'YK' in your BSN location?  That's Yukon, which is Canada.  Worth a double-check, at least.

Comment: Change to another country and then back, perhaps? (As an aside: Canada is so hard rock.)

Comment: suppressing my impulse to add an eh? at the end of this question...

Comment: Bioware lives in canada, so isn't canada the default?

Comment: @rarecandy Fair enough, that's the default but how can I change it to a non-default location?

Comment: It might be because you treat companies as plural. I think that's a Canadian/UK thing. Americans would say "Why *does* Bioware think I'm Canadian"? :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson it's a more friendly, personal thing, we treat companies as a collection of people like a family, you treat them as a monolithic, faceless entity! ;-)

Comment: @GAThrawn LOL +1 for the comment

Answer (score 8):

According to [this post](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/6/index/9717141) by a BioWare developer it depends on your [EA account settings](https://profile.ea.com). Change your country there and you should be good to go. It seems the default value is Canada.

EDIT: It seems you are far from being the only honorary Canadian out there but no matter how great of a site Gaming StackExchange is, there isn't anything we can help you with (well, besides our endless spiritual support, of course!). Perhaps you could try contacting BioWare via their official support channels and demand they threat you as the proud subject of Her Majesty the Queen you most definitely are. Or alternatively keep it calm and quiet until their grace bestows upon you a trip back from the colonies.

Comment: Default is Canada?! Weird, I seriously doubt their largest market is Canada

Comment: @Ben - Bioware is located in Canada.

Comment: @tugs is right, even in they forum "English" is chosen by the Canada's Flag not USA's flag.

Comment: @Gh0sT thanks, sounded likely, but my EA account is already set to UK